# AddActivity delete all command in menu bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-menu

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_delete_all -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, StatsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? I'n voting this to be a question of "very low quality".

Comment: @Harry Indig - I've fixed your code formatting and added the method declaration around it (I assumed this is Android Activity `onOptionsItemSelected`). You don't seem to have asked a question though... What is your goal? What have you tried so far?